# visual studio compile error with GAC_MSIL folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, gac-msil

I am doing an App in Visual Studio 2012. I installed Crystal Report 13.0.4 and when I run the application throws this error

```
 Error  2   the type 
'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFields' exists in  '
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Shared\v4.0_13.0.4000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll' as in '
c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Shared\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll'
```

I restarted the PC and the problem persists. I think I have to delete files in `c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Shared`

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks